# How can I open a JPanel that implements CytoPanelComponent from a context menu task?

Tags: cytoscape

I have a context menu task registered as a NodeViewTaskFactory.  When I select the context menu item, I want to open the custom JPanel (that implements CytoPanelComponent).

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(...);
registerService(context, myPanel, CytoPanelComponent.class, new Properties());
```

The panel is available in Cytoscape, but in my task the registrar can't find the service.

```
    public void run(final TaskMonitor taskMonitor) throws Exception {
        MyPanel view = registrar.getService(MyPanel.class);
```

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks,

- Mike

I was hoping to grab the service and open the Panel, but I get an error dialog that states: "Couldn't find service: ....MyPanel"

Answer (score 0):

You've registered the panel as a CytoPanelComponent, so you need to get it using that class.  You probably also want to register it with a property that allows you to get the specific CytoPanelComponent you want.  So, rather than an empty Properties() class, you might add an "id":

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("id", "MyPanel");
registerService(context, myPanel, CytoPanelComponent.class, props);
```

Then, when you want to get it back, you would:

```
MyPanel view = (MyPanel)registrar.getService(CytoPanelComponent.class, "(id=MyPanel)");
```